# Why Do We Keep Having to Re-Build Our React App to Test Changes?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app, mern

New to React, and excited to be getting started with it.

Followed the tutorial connected to [this project](https://github.com/didinj/mern-stack-authentication), which uses create-react-app to generate a new react application.

For some reason we can't test changes to the code live without re-building the entire app with `npm run build` (which is tedious and takes a long time).

Any pointers on how to get it to run the pre-built, non-production version of the app for development purposes?

This seems like it should be obvious, but for some reason we can't figure it out.

Comment: if you don't intend to modify client side code, you can use nodemon to automatically restart a server when the server code is modified.

Comment: if you want to change client-side code as well, you have two options: add webpack middleware to the current server, or run two servers: one for SPA (use CRA to create it or try existing react-scripts - it might work) and one for the api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `start` script to this:

```
"start": "react-scripts start",
```

And then use `npm start`.

The project you linked to has changed it. Most likely because they want to serve the app from a node.js application to showcase the security features they implemented.
I would say: Use another tutorial for now